# Angular 7/8/9 + Angular Material - sorting on same datasource from two tables

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular8, angular9

Is it possible to sort two html angular material tables together sharing same datasource.

Datasource: `[{rollNo: 1, name: 'a'}, {rollNo: 2, name: 'b'},{rollNo: 3, name: 'c'} ]`
For example html table A has column roll number, html table B has name . I want to sort both of them if user clicks on roll number or name.

Please note its a requirement to have two different html tables so I can't merge them.

Demo : http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uxjfqb

I understand we can have two datasource copy of each other and on one sort I can update another. So I can do that. But looking  for a better way here.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping Sort Object on the fly seem to do the trick

**Note that each sort has 3 states Original, Asc, Desc**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sxmukr